# View html5 with ie9 on server

Tags: css

Html page with *border-radius* and *box-shadow* works ok on my local machine and ie9
but when i try to view it from the server (mine and the hosting server) both the shadow and the corner radius are disappear.

There is no problem with chrome and safari.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css"> 
div
{
border:0px solid #a1a1a1;
padding:10px 40px; 
background:#2f3031;
width:900px;
height:1200px;
border-radius:8px;
-moz-border-radius:8px; /* Firefox 3.6 and earlier */
box-shadow: 8px 8px 5px #888888;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div><div/>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanx

Comment: What's installed on the server? Just because you have ie9 at home doesn't mean the server will.

Comment: Is your IE9 browser set to compatibility mode while viewing the page?

Comment: I don't think, that this will change the behaviour, but you should change the `<div/>` to `</div>`.

Comment: paulGraggix - now i saw that if i click the compatibillity buttun it works on my IIS but not on the site's server - any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

Your code isn't valid HTML5.

Start it with `<!DOCTYPE HTML>` to make IE9 render in standards mode from the server :)

Comment: Sorry for my absence. May be it is not HTML5 but the above code is working on my machine and doesnot work on 2 different servers.

Comment: Yes, but it wont work if it doesn't show itself as HTML5 from a server to IE9, i've had the same issue before, this is the solution.